# Convert a relational (InnoDB) database to an in-memory (Memory) database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to perform a couple of operations on my databases (Disk-based & In-memory) such as removing trailing spaces, joining ordering, aggregate, filter etc. Considering that I have obtained a disk-based database with dummy data is there a way to copy this data into an In-memory database so I can be able to compare the different speeds of the operations between the two databases in MySQL?
P.s this is for my research.
TIA

Comment: Export that database, then 1.Change the Database name then 2. change the `ENGINE = xxxx;` from INNODB to MEMORY and then IMPORT the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a table and fill it from another table:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (...) ENGINE=...
    SELECT ... FROM other_table;
```